# reindexing elastic search or updating indexes?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am now on elastic search, I cant figure out how to update elastic search index,type or document without deleting and reindexing? or is it the best way to achieve it?

So if I have products in my sql product table, should I better delete product type and reindex it or even entire DB as index on elasticsearc. what is the best use case and how can I achieve it?

I would like to do it with Nest preferably but if it is easier, ElasticSearch works for me as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be a real challenge! Historic records in elasticsearch will need to be reindexed when the template changes. New records will automatically be formatted according to the template you specify.

Using this link has helped us a lot:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html

You'll want to be sure to have the logstash filter set up to match the fields in your template.